# How can I put a interpolation in sass name of var

Tags: css, sass

I cant to math in the for loop the name of var with 
the nane  of the color var

[image: what i do]

i want this

[image: this what io]

Comment: Please post your code in the question, and make the question clearer. What are you trying to achieve, and what's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you have a minor syntax error with how interpolation works in general and I am sure it's doable with similar approach. Probably we will see an answer that corrects this error.

However, in your place I would go with this approach instead (probably in a file named _colors.scss):

```
$brown: (
 brown1: #000,
 brown2: #000,
 brown3: #000,
 brown4: #000,
 brown5: #000,
 brown6: #000
);

@each $key, $value in $brown {
  .txt-#{$key} {
    color: $value;
  }
}
```

It's called SASS maps and it's pretty powerful tool for much complex use cases as well. I suggest you look into it. This is a good start: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-sass-maps/